# Is Mona Sax the Murderer of Payne's family?

Tags: max-payne-2

Mona Sax is an assassin working for Alfred Woden. I was wondering if she is the assassin of  Max Payne's family. Vlad implied something along those lines, saying Payne should be thankful that he shot her.

So is Mona Sax the killer of Payne's family?

Comment: Do you mean that Mona had hired the Valkyr junkies or that she entered Max's house on the evening?

Comment: @user598527 The latter; I was wondering if she entered Max' house and shot his family as a hired assassin.

Comment: ...Using Valkyr addicts as a cover?

Comment: @user598527 Back in the day, I hadn't played the first Max Payne entry yet and didn't know the entire backstory. It was a fringe theory I had by some line of Vlad's dialogue that made me think if she was involved. See the accepted answer, it was just that: a fringe theory not backed up with any substantial evidence within the game. The question has been resolved for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's never implied so in the games.

Max's family murders was done by Valkyr drug addicts who broke into his house, at the time he was just a police officer, but this pushes Max towards becoming an undercover agent to try and stop the mafia gang who's trafficing the drug.

Only three years later, when he's undercover and they discover it they send Mona after him, he wasn't a target until then.